# How to setup my machine so I can reach my website from inside and outside my network?

Tags: networking, webserver, nat

I have a home web server and I cant access website from the external ip when inside my local network (due NAT loopback). Im trying to be able to seamlessly access my sites from outside and inside my local network so editing the hosts file is not going to work as far as I know. I cannot configure the NAT loopback settings on my router (supplied by xfinity).

Answer (score 0):

Using the HOSTS file is not going to be a permanent solution if you need access both internally and externally.  You may want to look into something like [Dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) as a more permanent solution.

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with dynamic dns (I use it to access my server outside my local network). As far as I know it wont help, because it still links (im sure there is a better word) back to your external IP (it just is a way to get around DHCP as far as I know). No matter what i cant access my server using the external IP because of NAT loopback which cant be fixed on my router.

Comment: According to [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback), you should be able to configure your router and create a custom rule in the routing table to utilize NAT Loopback to make it work.  What model router do you have?  Do you know for sure your router does not support NAT Loopback?

Comment: The router for sure doesn't support changing NAT loopback settings